# combobox for ASP.NET (with or without AjaxControlToolkit)

Tags: asp.net, combobox

I would need a combobox for an ASP.NET site.
So the control needs to:

1) - offer several options to be picked up via a dropdown list

2) - let the user write a string that is not present into the dropdown list.

This combobox control already exists (and works fine) in C# for **windows applications**.
But into ASP.NET default controls, there are no such comboboxes. There is just a dropdown list (1) and a textbox (2).
The dropdown list does not let you set a My_DropDownList.Text with a string that does not belong to the control's ItemList.

I googled a bit, tested a few custom controls that did not work as I expected.
Then I found out about AjaxControlToolkit.
It is supposed to offer the exact ComboBox that I need for ASP.Net.

I installed the package, added an ajax ScriptManager as pre-requested and then added the ComboBox.
It looks that you can change the My_ComboBox.Text with a new value, but this new value has to belong to the control's ListItem.
Otherwise I get the error:
"... has a SelectedValue which is invalid because it does not exist in the list of items"

Did I miss anything? My understanding was that we were supposed to be able to set any value into the combobox (as for the default C# combobox provided by VS for win applications).

Alternatively, do you know about any other controls that that I could add to avoid this problem?

Of course, I would have the possibility to do something like:

```
My_ComboBox.Add(new ListItem("my_String");
My_ComboBox.Text = "my_String";
```

But I am pretty sure you ll offer me more elegant solutions.

Thx in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your mental model of a ComboBox might be "a TextBox with a helpful auto-complete list". However, that's not what the AjaxControlToolkit ComboBox is: Rather, it's a Dropdown which automatically adds new items that are entered by the user.

Thus, from a code perspective, it behaves more like a Dropdown rather than like a TextBox. Your understanding is correct: To set the text to a previously unknown entry, you need to add it to the list first. If the text is entered *by the user*, this is done automatically.

If your use case would rather need "a TextBox with a helpful auto-complete list", I'd stop searching for a ComboBox and start investingating auto-complete text boxes instead.